# How to use SetDisplayConfig (windows-rs) to force screen re-detection?

Tags: windows, rust, graphics

I am using windows-rs (Latest version from GitHub, because it contains some fixes the stable version on Crates.io doesn't have).

My goal is to develop a small software that automatically forces the screen to be re-detected and set to the highest resolution (It's for a school with a weird setup where teachers have to turn projectors on before the PC for resolutions to get detected, but often forget that, leading the PCs to have a very low resolution, and the higher resolutions not being detected).

For re-initializing the screen, I have the following function:

```
// Some imports may be unused here, I haven't checked them yet, the full file has more functions
use windows::Win32::Graphics::Gdi::{ChangeDisplaySettingsA, EnumDisplaySettingsA, DEVMODEA, SDC_FORCE_MODE_ENUMERATION, SDC_APPLY, SDC_SAVE_TO_DATABASE, SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG, QDC_ALL_PATHS};
use windows::Win32::Media::Audio::Endpoints::IAudioEndpointVolume;
use windows::Win32::Media::Audio::{IMMDeviceEnumerator, MMDeviceEnumerator};
use windows::Win32::Devices::Display::{GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes, QueryDisplayConfig, SetDisplayConfig, DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID};

use windows::core::GUID;
use windows::Win32::System::Com::{CoInitialize, CoCreateInstance, CLSCTX_ALL};

// Forces Windows to reinit display settings
pub fn force_reinit_screen() -> i32 {
    let mut path_count = 0;
    let mut mode_count = 0;
    let result = unsafe { GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATHS, &mut path_count, &mut mode_count) };
    println!("GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes returned {}", result);
    let mut path_array = Vec::with_capacity(path_count as usize);
    let mut mode_array = Vec::with_capacity(mode_count as usize);
    let result = unsafe {
        QueryDisplayConfig(
            QDC_ALL_PATHS,
            &mut path_count,
            path_array.as_mut_ptr(),
            &mut mode_count,
            mode_array.as_mut_ptr(),
            ::core::mem::transmute(::core::ptr::null::<DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID>()),
        )
    };
    println!("QueryDisplayConfig returned {}", result);
    let flags = SDC_FORCE_MODE_ENUMERATION | SDC_APPLY | SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG | SDC_SAVE_TO_DATABASE;

   let result = unsafe { SetDisplayConfig(Some(&path_array), Some(&mode_array), flags) };
   result
}
```

However, it does not work on any computer I've tried this on (Returns code 87, which seems to mean bad parameters). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even though "beamers" may be the colloquial term in your local dialect, you're going to have trouble finding the documentation you need unless you learn and start using the standard terminology in the Redmond, WA, USA dialect.  I *think* you mean "projectors".

Comment: Which function returns 87?  Is that the actual return code of the WinAPI function or is it coming from `GetLastError()`?

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry about the mistake regarding projectors, I'll edit the question, but the type of screen is not really relevant for this, I just wanted to add it to explain why I was using this function. `87` is the return code of `SetDisplayConfig()`, QueryDisplayConfig works fine (returns `0`)

Comment: I mentioned the terminology only because Windows does use it in both [user documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-to-a-projector-or-pc-7e170c39-58dc-c866-7d55-be2372632892) and [some API names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager)

Comment: May I suggest also including the number of paths and number of modes in your debug output?  Both before and after the `QueryDisplayConfig()` call (it could be significant if QDC changes those values)

Comment: @BenVoigt I added logging now, there is one display path and two display modes both before and after the function, so it does not seem to be changed.

Comment: Do any of the paths have the `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_ACTIVE` flag set?  Doc says "Only the paths within this array that have the `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_ACTIVE` flag set in the flags member of `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO` are set."